# OBIEE: I can't schedule reports. Unauthorized Access: please contact the administrator

Tags: oracle, obiee, oracle-bi, oas

I have reports and analysis in "My Folders".
When I click on analysis "More" -> "Schedule" everythink is OK.
When I click on reports "More" -> "Schedule" I have error "Unauthorized Access. Please contact the administrator".

I can open report, but I can't add to schedule.
OBIEE 12.2.1.4.0

What can I do?
Please help

Comment: "Please contact the administrator" - so, did you do that?

Comment: I am administrator :-) I think it is problem in permissions

Answer (score 0):

OBI Jeopardy: What are application policies.